# android Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I get this error when trying to use a thread.

`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

```
    Thread anOpenConnectionThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            try
            {
                openConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {

                          Toast.makeText(LaunchApp.this, "Opening connection with " + ip + " failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                 });

                EneterTrace.error("Open connection failed.", err);
            }
        }
    });
```

Starting the thread in the onCreate:

```
anOpenConnectionThread.start();
```

The open connection code just in case:

```
private void openConnection() throws Exception
{
    // Create sender sending MyRequest and as a response receiving MyResponse
    IDuplexTypedMessagesFactory aSenderFactory = new DuplexTypedMessagesFactory();
    mySender = aSenderFactory.createDuplexTypedMessageSender(MyResponse.class, MyRequest.class);

    // Subscribe to receive response messages.
    mySender.responseReceived().subscribe(myOnResponseHandler);

    // Create TCP messaging for the communication.
    ip = sProfile.getIp();
    IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new TcpMessagingSystemFactory();
    IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel
        = aMessaging.createDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://" + ip + ":8060/");
    Toast.makeText(this, ip, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Attach the output channel to the sender and be able to send
    // messages and receive responses.
    mySender.attachDuplexOutputChannel(anOutputChannel);
}
```

sProfile is initialized!
This is where the ip is being set(It shows the ip in the toast so I'm 100% sure it's not null)

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            int pos = profileSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
            currentIp = myDb.getIp(pos);
            Toast.makeText(SelectProfile.this, currentIp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

getIp is returning the ip set in there.

```
public String getIp()
{
    return currentIp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the thread's run method you have `openConnection()`. In `openConnection()` you have the below

```
   Toast.makeText(this, ip, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Updating ui from a thread not posssible.

Comment: Thanks that is fixed now. But the it now says ip = null?
Gives an error on connecting with tcp://null:8060

Comment: check this `ip = sProfile.getIp()` this is null is  `sProfile` initialized?

Comment: Yes
SelectProfile sProfile;
in the onCreate I have: sProfile = new SelectProfile();

Also: in the SelectProfile class getIp function I have the following:
 public String getIp()
 {
  return currentIp;
 }

The ip is being set here:
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
       int pos = profileSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
       currentIp = myDb.getIp(pos);
       Toast.makeText(SelectProfile.this, currentIp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

and the toast works fine and shows the ip

Comment: then your `sProfile.getIp()` is returning null. so make sure it doe snot return null and it should work. BTW i haven't worked on that. to the question posted i have answered

Comment: Also: in the SelectProfile class getIp function I have the following:
 public String getIp()
 {
  return currentIp;
 }

The ip is being set here:
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
       int pos = profileSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
       currentIp = myDb.getIp(pos);
       Toast.makeText(SelectProfile.this, currentIp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

and the toast works fine and shows the ip

Comment: IS SelectProfile and activity class?

Comment: Yes it is an activity class

Comment: @TheJetse you should not create an isntance of a activity class which is wrong. Activtity has a ui a lifecycle and is started by startActivtiy. You can use `startActivtiyForResult` in mainactivity to get the ip from SelectUserProfile